# Add 0 as last value in c program

Tags: c, arrays

Im doing a little program in c, everything works perfectly but in one process i have to assign some values to an array, but i want the last value is 0 automatically

```
printf("cantidad de valores codificados a ingresar "); /*amount of values to enter*/
scanf("%d",&l);

printf("\ningrese los valores a decodificar: "); /*entering values*/

for(i=0;i<l;++i) {
    scanf("\n%d ",&c[i]);
}
```

Comment: `l` is a really bad choice for single letter variable. Also you really should have whitespace only at one side (if at all) of the scanf() conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to assign 0 to the element after the one read by `scanf`:

```
for(i=0;i<l;++i) {
    scanf("%d",&c[i]);
}
c[i] = 0;
```

You have declared `i` before the loop, so it's OK. Make sure `i` is not greater then size of the array `c`. So, assuming `c` is defined as, for example:

```
int c[100];
```

After you you read in the value of `l` you should check if it's not greater than the size of the array like this:

```
scanf("%d",&l);
if (l + 1 > sizeof(c) / sizeof(int)) // one extra for the 0
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Too many values, I don't have this much space...");
  exit(1);
}
```

But it would be better to allocate the array `c` dynamically:

```
scanf("%d",&l);
int* c = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * (l + 1));
```

Comment: the final value of `i` would be `l` ryt? That would be one greater than array size?

Comment: what will happen `scanf` with `\n`?

Comment: `l` is not size of array here, this is a value read from stdin indicating number of values to follow.

Comment: @mani `\n` was actually not needed, I removed it now, thanks.

Comment: `c` is declared as `int c[50]` and the amount of values are much lower than that (28 max), the extra value must be added as last value, `l-1` are the values to enter and `l` is the last value that i wanted to be 0 automatically

Comment: Not really, i did what you suggest, but the results are different (and wrong) than the results that gives me entering 0 value manually

Comment: Nevermind, im a noob, as @pmg suggested i had a whitespace at both sides of scanf(), i deleted it `scanf("%d",&l);` and everything works perfectly now, thanks to all, this is a great comunity

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<l;++i){
   scanf("\n%d ",&c[i]);
}

c[l] = 0;
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun At this point, `i == l` (as we just left the loop) so it doesn't matter.